# Error: While Using Gdal library with Python anaconda Distribution

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, gdal

I am using Python with anaconda distribution for converting a satellite image to array for further processing.But while using .ReadAsArray() function the below error is occurring.I have tried to search about the error but no proper results are coming.I have installed everything using conda command.

```
from osgeo import gdal
    ds = gdal.Open('/home/alay/Desktop/Studies/2010/ndvi01jun2010.tif')
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    img= band.ReadAsArray()
```

The error occuring after executing the above code

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py in 
swig_import_helper()
     17         try:
---> 18             fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_gdal_array', [dirname(__file__)])
     19         except ImportError:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py in find_module(name, path)
    296     else:
--> 297         raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
    298 

ImportError: No module named '_gdal_array'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-eae4e7981f3a> in <module>()
----> 1 img= band.ReadAsArray()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py in ReadAsArray(self, xoff, yoff, win_xsize, win_ysize, buf_xsize, buf_ysize, buf_type, buf_obj, resample_alg, callback, callback_data)
   2603         parameters should generally not be specified if buf_obj is specified. The array is returned"""
   2604 
-> 2605         from . import gdalnumeric
   2606 
   2607         return gdalnumeric.BandReadAsArray( self, xoff, yoff,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/gdalnumeric.py in <module>()
----> 1 from osgeo.gdal_array import *
      2 from numpy import *

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py in <module>()
     26                 fp.close()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _gdal_array = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper
     30 else:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py in swig_import_helper()
     18             fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_gdal_array', [dirname(__file__)])
     19         except ImportError:
---> 20             import _gdal_array
     21             return _gdal_array
     22         if fp is not None:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal_array'
```

Comment: You seem to have local (i.e. cross-distribution) packages installed too. Try mv'inf ~/.local to some other place and see if the problem clears up.

Comment: did you ever fix this issue? I am having the same problem even without Anaconda. Gdal 2.2.1, Python 3.6.6 on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Yeah i had the error because the gdal was pointing to some other gdal folder installed.If you can see the error the path is showing ~/.local.... But my gdal was in anaconda packages.So try to deleting the folder or change the path variable such that the anaconda path is before the local path